# Does "entre quatre yeux" carry a confrontational connotation, unlike "unter vier Augen" in German?

Tags: expressions, allemand

In conversation with my colleague, I said:

> Wenn es dir nichts ausmacht, würde ich mich gerne **unter vier Augen** mit ihm unterhalten. Währenddessen könntest du nach Irina suchen.

This is where in French I'd have said:

> Si cela ne te dérange pas, j'aimerais m'entretenir avec lui **en privé**. Peut-être pourrais-tu aller chercher Irina, pendant ce temps?

Now I'm wondering if I can use "*entre quatre yeux*" in this context, too?

> Si cela ne te dérange pas, j'aimerais m'entretenir avec lui **entre quatre yeux**. Peut-être pourrais-tu aller chercher Irina, pendant ce temps?

The "*unter vier Augen {under four eyes}*" in German is used neutrally in the sense of "*en privé*".

But  does "*entre quatre yeux*" always have a negative, confrontational connotaion of "***angrily*** talking to someone privately"? -- perhaps, in a tone similar to that of "*Can I have a word with you?*" in English which often implies that the speaker has something negative to say, be it a warning or a scolding.

Comment: On l'utilise pour dire [en privé](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/entre_quatre_yeux).  Et tu connais la prononciation habituelle ? Par contre on trouve rarement écrit *entre quatre-z-yeux*.

Comment: Oui. C'est la façon dont je le prononce. @Laure

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is usually used for a face-to-face exchange.

*Dictionnaire Historique de la langue française* :

> en tête à tête, seul à seul.

*Grand Larousse* :

> en particulier, en tête à tête.

But we must consider that when we need to talk to someone face to face we don't always have nice things to tell them. Therefore the sentence often implies that we are going to reproach them with something. As this [cartoon](https://www.journaldunet.com/management/efficacite-personnelle/1175724-ce-que-ces-gestes-disent-de-vous/1175805-se-placer-en-face-a-face) puts it :

> Tout le monde connaît les expressions "se parler en face à face" ou "se parler entre quatre yeux".
>   Elles signifient souvent la mise en place d'un rapport de force, voire d'une certaine tension.

The definition in the [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/yeux) is:

> ♦ Entre quat'z'yeux (fam.). En privé.

But the sentence given as an example with the use of the verb *éreinter* clearly states Flaubert intends to villify SAinte-Beuve.

> *Présentement je m'amuse beaucoup, étant en train d'éreinter mon petit ami Sainte-Beuve dans le silence du cabinet et entre quatre z'yeux* (Flaub., *Corresp*., 1862, p.310).

Comment: I get the impression that the synonym "*un tête-à-tête*", on the other hand, carries a positive connotation and is rarely used negatively.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens *en tête à tête*  just means "one-to-one", it's rather neutral if no special context is specified. *Ils ont eu une explication musclée en tête à tête.*  vs *Ils se sont retrouvés en tête à tête et elle en a profité pour l'embrasser.*  It's the context (*explication musclée/embrasser*) that gives the positive or negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it mean only that it will be/stay a private exchange. No positive or negative connotation.